# Crystal Disk Info, SSD. NTFS corrupted

Tags: ssd, performance, ntfs, crystaldiskinfo

My 128GB SSD is configured in RAID1. According to the technical specs it has 100TBW. Total host writes is now more then 150 000GB. The filesystem is getting corrupted all the time.

I think this SSD is not designed for such write output. Average 6MB/s , 24/7. Temporary camera images that are deleted after verification.

Should I switch to a more high end and larger SSD?

[image]

Comment: In my opinion you should replace it. And this is the issue with this question, you're basically asking for opinions, see: https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Yes, change it to NAS grade SSD.

Answer (score 2):

Your disk SMART report shows no errors. The `100` values may be confusing,
but they are normalized values that actually mean "no error".

The disk seems to be in perfect health, although it shows that it was
heavily used. The Total Host Writes number is not a reliable parameter
(I have seen other cases where the number was clearly nonsense).
The disk's rating of 100TBW doesn't mean that it can't do much more -
it is after all an enterprise-grade disk.

From these SMART values, I see no fault in the disk that can explain
its file-system being corrupted. I doubt that the problem is with the disk.

If you have no confidence in the disk, you may replace it, but the
decision is up to you.

Comment: Could the unexpected power loss count be responsible for the ntfs corruption?

Comment: Yes, that is entirely possible, especially if the disk is heavily used for writing, so that parts of the file-system metadata was still in memory and was lost.